# What Exactly is Preventing NivoSlider from Scaling Pictures Down Automatically when the Site is on Mobile View?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, image-resizing, nivo-slider

I’ve been trying to make our “normal” website mobile friendly by using CSS´s media queries and after successfully resizing the NivoSlider to fit the smaller screen on mobile portrait mode I’ve been stuck at having the slider not being able to resize the pictures themselves automatically. The pictures should fit the new smaller viewport/slider size instead of just showing cropped, non scaled-down versions of them.

I have read answers to similar questions on this site and tried to turn the width to 100% and height to “auto !important!; “ but I’m still getting no results. What could I try? The slider is using the Default Theme. Here’s a link to the website:

[www.sandino-hostel-berlin.de](http://www.sandino-hostel-berlin.de)

I’ve added the media query details to custom.css which I keep commented out so that people visiting the site on mobile won´t see my css testing mess. I´ve tried to changed the width and height of the slider there (custom.css) as well as in nivo-slider.css and default.css but dice. Thank you very much for your help in advance and I’ll try to provide more technical details as they are needed.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ```object-fit``` property on the image to either ```cover``` or ```contain```?

Comment: I took a quick look at the site and your slider is a bit more complicated than I first thought. The ```#container```, ```#wrapper``` and the ```table``` should all have their width set to 100%. Then you can set the ```background-size``` property to either ```cover``` or ```contain```. The ```background-position``` should be set to ```center```. You're still not quite there yet, but part of your CSS seems to be controlled by JavaScript (e.g. the height) so I don't know precisely what will happen if you were to load the page with those settings.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help Jelmer, I’m  sorry and embarrassed for my late response. I’ve tried the changes you suggested in custom.css but no results yet, do mean adding the background-size property and background-position to the pictures themseves?  I´ll try these changes in the nivo-slider.css files as well and see if I can get positive results.